# Which kit to replace a basic toggle switch

Tags: motherboard, switch, video-camera, ip-camera

Our CCTV server has been down for days and the reason seems quite obvious: the switch to start/stop it has melt. 
[image]
Hopefully the motherboard is OK.
So we are looking for a complete kit to replace the switch:
[image]
The contact looks quite basic with I guess the switch connecting the two pins:
[image]
The name of the components would be a good start, or references to buy quickly perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damaged switch is known as a single pole single throw rocker switch, also SPST rocker switch. The only critical aspect of this switch is the size of the opening. Conveniently, you have the opening at hand and take measurements to match the resource you choose. Amazon and eBay will have this item, although my search on Amazon produced less rectangular shaped switches. eBay search results abound with more appropriate looking shapes of varying sizes. Small, medium and large.

[McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/rocker-switches/rocker-switches-8/) is another source. Note that the options are for NO and NC, normally open and normally closed. You'd want NO which means the switch is off unless activated. Steer away from M marked switches, which means Momentary, requiring that the switch be held in order for it to be on.

The connector on the switch can be found locally, specifically at an auto parts supply store. Bring the new switch with you to ensure you get the right size connector and splice a pair on the existing pigtail. Polarity/position doesn't matter for this sort of installation.

A switch should not fail in the manner shown. This implies that the current capacity was under-valued or there is a problem with the device causing more current to be drawn than expected. Your replacement switch may experience the same problem. It is advised to monitor the switch for high temperature at the connectors immediately after installation and periodically after.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. :-) We'll check that, hopefully parts are easily available.

Comment: Note edit for one more consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, indeed, and I hope the motherboard is not KO.
I've ordered the switches, we'll see if the server restarts as expected once fixed.